# Gridview select commandfield not firing in updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I click the select button in the gridview which is inside an updatepanel and everything executes besides this.

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "open", "window.open('" + Redirect + "','Setup','width=500,height=200,0,status=0,');", true);

Redirect is a link in the gridview row.

It works perfect, outside the updatepanel.

How do you think I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to add JavaScript to the page during an asynchronous postback. I would suggest using `OnClientClick` with some databinding syntax instead.

Something like this might work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" 
    OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("void(window.open('{0}'));return false;", Eval("Redirect")) %>' />
```

This approach might actually work better actually, because it saves you an unnecessary postback.

Comment: Thanks That would work great, although how am I able to use the values from the gridview as querystring parameters. As that is what redirect consists of.